# Meta Viewport Dynamic Change on Android Default Browser (not Chrome)

Tags: jquery, html, viewport

I'm trying to dynamically change `<meta name="viewport">`.

I have it set by default like:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

And when the screen resolution goes below `768px` I want viewport to be change to:
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=768">`.

For this I use jQ code:

```
var winW,
    initVP,
    newVP = "width=768";

$(document).on({
    ready: function(){
        winW = $(window).width();
    }
});

$(window).on({
    load: function(){
        if ( winW < 768 ) { setViewport( newVP ); }
    }
});

function setViewport( content ) {
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content',content);
}
```

But for some reason this change doesn't affect Google Nexus 7's Default browser (not Chrome but the lame one that was before) in any visible way. I can see that changes are made in the `<head>` section, and `<meta name="viewport" content="` is changed to `width=768">`, but the browser doesn't seem to react to this change.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

EDIT: as **zsaat14** mentioned Nexus7 has 800px width according to the specs. Nevertheless browser always return 600px width (see the screenshot here). In my case of Android emulator it returns 602px though %)

[image: Browser alerting $(window).width();]

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 7 has a screen resolution of 1280X800 ([source](http://www.google.com/nexus/7/specs/)).  It is somewhat surprising then that the meta tag is changing, but not surprising that your website stays the same.

EDIT:
Ok, so it's not the width then.  You might try reading this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_width_and_screen_width) from MDN and make sure that the meta viewport can do what you are expecting.  It is not quite clear what you want it to do, but the meta viewport tag does not make drastic changes, so you might just be missing it.

Comment: Good point! Yes according to the specs it does but the thing is the browser always return 600px width ... I need to update the question. Thanks for this remark!